# Express non-linear algebraic equation in terms of variable $\nu$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation that I would like write explicitly in terms of $\nu$,
$$\frac{8\epsilon\gamma^2}{A(8\epsilon\gamma^2)-\nu^2}\left[\lambda-\frac{\beta\nu}{2\gamma}E_1+\frac{\beta\nu^2}{8\epsilon\gamma^2}E_2\right]-\left(\frac{2\beta\epsilon\gamma\nu}{A(8\epsilon\gamma^2)-\nu^2}E_3+\frac{\beta\nu^2}{8\epsilon\gamma^2}E_4\right)^2 = 0,$$
where $\epsilon,\gamma,\lambda,E_1,E_2,E_3$ and $E_4$ are constants. Is there any way one can do this? Advise on close approximations or simplification techniques will also be very much appreciated.

Comment: Unless this is an exercise from a greek text book, I wonder how could that equation be written in a more annoying way...

Comment: That equation is expressed in terms of $\nu$ already. As DonAntonio pointed out it could be beautified by using some abbreviations for stuff that appears twice.

Comment: @KurtG. What I meant to ask is if there is a way to explicitly express things in terms of $\nu=...$ . I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: That's not clearer. Are you asking to find $\nu$ ? If so, what polynomial in $\nu$ do you ge by rearranging this equation ? Abbreviate everything that is not interesting so that you have only coefficients $a_i$ of $\nu^i$.